# не типичный вывод констант php

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, есть константы `rank1`, `rank2`, `rank3`

Когда я обрабатываю определенные данные, я получаю число, и хотелось бы как-то, чтобы не использовать много кода, в зависимости от числа вывести константу с окончанием равным этому числу. То есть, что-то наподобие:

```
$int = 1
echo rank . $int
```

и чтобы в итоге вывело константу `rank1`

Спасибо.

Comment: Может вам лучше массив с этими константами создать?

Answer (score 2):

в одном из ответов вам уже привели ссылку на документацию. К сожалению дальше ссылки абзаца текста там дело не пошло. А дальше написано вот что:

> Также вы можете использовать функцию constant() для получения значения
>   константы, если вы формируете имя константы динамически.

так что ваша задумка должна выглядеть следующим образом:

```
define('RANK1', 'ла ла ла');
const   RANK2 = 'а-та-та';

$int = 1;
echo constant("RANK$int");
```

Answer (score 0):

Нельзя.

Для начала, документация: 
http://php.net/manual/ru/language.constants.syntax.php

> Если использована конструкция const, константы могут содержать только
>   скалярные данные (boolean, integer, float и string типов). С PHP 5.6
>   возможно также определять константы как скалярные выражения, и также
>   можно определять константы с типом array. Можно определять константы с
>   типом resource, но не рекомендуется, так как может привести к
>   неожиданным результатам.

Соответственно, создаем что-то вроде:

```
const('Rank', array('1'=>'qwe','2'=>'asd');
```

Далее обращаемся^

```
Rank[1];
```

Comment: привести ссылку на документацию и не прочитать ему самому, серьезно?

Answer (score -1):

Если бы можно было в php динамически вызывать константы, в таком случае все очень просто, а так придется создавать массив со всеми именами констант, но в таком случае можно и вообще без констант обойтись)

Comment: Тупо вместо констант использовать элементы массива.

Comment: $arr = ['el1' => 'первый', 'el2' => 'второй', 'el3' => 'третий']; 

$n = 2;

echo $arr["el$n"];